# Asterisk dialplan several apps simultaneously

Tags: asterisk, pbx, telephony

I am designing an Asterisk 11 Dialplan for a call center.

I am facing a problem in dialplan. In order to achieve the desired configuration , i think it is necessary to run 2 applications at the same time at some point in the dialplan.

Example:

```
[context-name]
exten => _37150258[67],1,Ringing()
same => n,Wait(2)
same => n,Answer()
same => n,Playback(welcome-message)
same => n,Park() AND Dial(somebody)
...
```

I see this aproach necessary as the logic behind is:

The caller dials call-center's number

- Asterisk answers, greets him
- Asterisk puts the call on hold/park while looking for an available operator
- Operator picks up the call

Would it be possible to run Park() and Dial() simultaneously, or should I consider a different aproach for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk already has this in place. You just need to setup a "call queue". http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+call+queues
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIulFoe4r3s

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches possible.  The first thing you need to understand is the concept of putting a call on "hold" while you dial a number.  In practical terms Asterisk does this whenever a Dial is in progress.  You can even play specific audio to tell the caller you are dialing (or on hold).

Depending on what you want to do if no one answers, that's where you might have to use a queue.  But I suspect just remove the Park from your example to experiment and you'll see what I mean.